# Modifying a dataset after setting it in an Object

Tags: java, setter

I have a Java question, but more object oriented related.

```
public class A {

    private List list;

    public A() {
        this.list = new ArrayList();
    }

    public List getList() {
        return this.list;
    }

    public void setList(List new_list) {
        this.list = new_list;
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A a = new A();
        List my_list = new ArrayList();
        a.setList(my_list);
        my_list.add("bla");
    }
}
```

The question: Is it allowed to the caller (main() in this example) to assume that setList(...) saves the reference to the List object?

To be specific - the last code line in the main() method - adding "bla" to my_list and assuming it will be added to A object's List as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should add more tags to this question...

Comment: What is the problem now?

Comment: Since you've put up a good example as well, I was curious if there was something you weren't able to test by using the debugger? (or even by a bunch of ``println()``'s, if you're comfortable that way)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simply **yes**. Every assignment in Java uses the object reference by default, except for native types like `int`.

Comment: I agree it will work. The question is a matter of best practice.
With the current caller code, changing the private dataset (list) to a different type (Map for instance) will require to instantiate a new type in setList(...), therefore adding "bla" to my_list won't reflect in the Map.
In a design perspective, can A.setList(...) caller assume A keeps the List's reference?

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with the references, not the real objects. Therefore when you call

```
List my_list = new ArrayList();
a.setList(my_list);
```

a reference to *my_list* is stored in *a.list*. Therefore you have two references of the same *List* object in your code *my_list* and *a.list*. Now, when you call

my_list.add("bla");

"bla" is added into the *List* object, which is being referred by *a.list* also. If you replace the above call by

```
a.getList().add("bla");
```

You would get the same result.

Comment: I agree it will work. The question is a matter of best practice. With the current caller code, changing the private dataset (list) to a different type (Map for instance) will require to instantiate a new type in setList(...), therefore adding "bla" to my_list won't reflect in the Map. In a design perspective, can A.setList(...) caller assume A keeps the List's reference?

Comment: I don't see any bad practice in the above discussed approach. Even you can modify the List objects after adding them. Modifications of objects in Set and Values in Map is not a best practice. Java doesn't grantees the behavior of the Set or Map object once any set member or map value if modified after adding. In your case you are just adding by another reference: that's perfectly okay. It compromises readability only, not your outcome.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the caller (`main` method) has a reference to the same list as the class `A`.

I think there is two options:

- The setter method just save the reference (as in your code)
- The setter method makes a preventive copy

The usual way that I see in my developer life is to save the reference. If you want to do a preventive copy, I think that should be in the javadoc. There is also people who always return an immutable version of the list to prevent modification of the state of your object. The choice is more about what you are doing here. If the do not trust the caller of your code, then do a preventive copy.